# Can my users purchase inapp products if I have "Your payments Settings need attention" error?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have an android app which offers paid features in form of in-app purchases.

I have this error on my console Play dashboard. It means I still need to set a payment method to let Google pay me (not to let users pay for the inapp products, that's already implemented and working)

[image]

I'm planning to do so as soon as possible but in the meantime can my users purchase in-app products or everything is halted? I can't tell from the dashboard and nowhere it's explained